# Papyrus 0.9.0M6 Installation to Eclipse Juno cannot be completed

Tags: eclipse, papyrus

While installing Papyrus 0.9.0M6 to Eclipse Juno through the downloaded .Zip file,

Juno says,

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Papyrus SDK Binaries (Incubation) 0.9.0.v201203211542 (org.eclipse.papyrus.sdk.feature.feature.group 0.9.0.v201203211542)
Missing requirement: XWT (Incubation) 0.9.1.v20110603 (org.eclipse.e4.xwt 0.9.1.v20110603)

### requires 'bundle org.pushingpixels.trident 1.2.0' but it could not be found

Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: XWT UI Plug-in (Incubation) 0.9.0.v20101021 (org.eclipse.e4.xwt.tools.ui 0.9.0.v20101021)
To: bundle org.eclipse.e4.xwt 0.0.0
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Papyrus SDK Binaries (Incubation) 0.9.0.v201203211542 (org.eclipse.papyrus.sdk.feature.feature.group 0.9.0.v201203211542)
To: org.eclipse.e4.xwt.tools.ui [0.9.0.v20101021]

---

I couldn't get 'org.pushingpixels.trident 1.2.0' from anywhere.

When I install Papyrus through 'Help > Install Modelling Components > Papyrus',
Juno produces an error without exception stack trace.

Where can I get that pushingpixels bundle to successfully install Papyrus 0.9.0M6 to Juno.

If that bundle is needed to install Papyrus 0.9.0M6 to Juno,
I suggest Papyrus should include that bundle in their release.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make Papyrus0.9.0M6 work in Eclipse Juno 4.2,
we need to install other plug-ins below.

- **EMF** Facet SDK
- Operational **QVT** SDK
- **MoDisco** SDK
- **WST** XML Core
- **xText** SDK
- **OCL** Examples and Editors
- Subversive **SVN** Team Provider

All of them can be found on Juno Update Site, filter with Bold letters above.

I don'k know which of them includes 'org.pushingpixels.trident',
but you will see 'org.pushingpixels.trident' in the Package Explorer after you install all above successfully.