# Cannot install papyrus on eclipse juno

Tags: eclipse, papyrus

I have downloaded the papyrus zip file for eclipse juno and get this error while installing:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Papyrus SysML ModelExplorer (Incubation) 0.10.1.v201310020936 (org.eclipse.papyrus.sysml.modelexplorer.feature.feature.group 0.10.1.v201310020936)
  Missing requirement: Papyrus Tools (Incubation) 0.10.1.v201310020936 (org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.tools 0.10.1.v201310020936) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.core.expressions 3.4.500' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Papyrus Backbone (Incubation) 0.10.1.v201310020936 (org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core 0.10.1.v201310020936)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.tools 0.10.1
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Papyrus Edit Service (Incubation) 0.10.1.v201310020936 (org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.services.edit 0.10.1.v201310020936)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.core 0.10.1
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: ModelExplorer customization for SysML (Incubation) 0.10.1.v201310020936 (org.eclipse.papyrus.sysml.modelexplorer 0.10.1.v201310020936)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.papyrus.infra.services.edit 0.10.1
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Papyrus SysML ModelExplorer (Incubation) 0.10.1.v201310020936 (org.eclipse.papyrus.sysml.modelexplorer.feature.feature.group 0.10.1.v201310020936)
    To: org.eclipse.papyrus.sysml.modelexplorer [0.10.1.v201310020936]
```

I have already installed the plugins mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10597122/1333899)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Papyrus 0.10.X requires Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler). You should use 0.9.2 using this update site: http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/papyrus/updates/releases/juno